# Entity-relationship diagram

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I am very confused with one of the questions for my coming exam in databases.

I am given a scenario with details. First question is:

> Draw an entity-relationship (ER) diagram for this problem, clearly labelling the entities and relationships and showing the cardinalities of the relationships. Include the primary keys of each entity."

I am fine with this however I really don't get the second question:

> "Identify the main attributes for each entity and relationship of your ER diagram and include any foreign keys needed. Hence derive a set of relations for the model.

Could someone please explain what is required for second question?

Comment: After reading the wikipedia articles on the ER model and ER diagrams, what is one word or part of that sentence that you don't understand?

Comment: Unfortinately entire question is unclear for me, I don't understant what is required from me, because it feels like I will already be answering question 2 with my question 1 answer, but I know its wrong.

Comment: Question 1 asks for an ER diagram that distinguishes entities and relationships. Question 2 asks for a set of relations that include dependent attributes and foreign keys. ER diagrams don't directly indicate foreign keys, and it sounds like dependent attributes can be excluded from question 1. A relational model just depicts relations, it doesn't distinguish between entity relations and relationship relations.

Answer (score 1):

I think question 2 contains question 1 and a bit more.

In question 2, in addition to identifying the main attributes, you need to identify any other foreign key attributes that are not already in the problem. Then you need to use these new attributes to create more relationships.